# Broken dependencies while installing any software

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, software-center, dependencies

Whenever I try to install any software using ubuntu software center or from command line, I get this dependency problem. I cant seem to resolve dependencies easily

```
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-18 is installed
libc6 : Breaks: locales (< 2.19) but 2.13+git20120306-3 is installed
libc6:i386 : Recommends: libc6-i686:i386
          Breaks: locales (< 2.19) but 2.13+git20120306-3 is installed
libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.7) but 2.19-18 is installed
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.7) but 2.19-18 is installed
libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.7) but 2.19-18 is installed
libnih1 : PreDepends: libc6 (< 2.16) but 2.19-18 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

The output of apt-get cache policy libc-dev-bin

```
libc-dev-bin:
Installed: 2.15-0ubuntu10.7
Candidate: 2.15-0ubuntu10.12
Version table:
2.15-0ubuntu10.12 0
    500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
2.15-0ubuntu10.11 0
    500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
   500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
*** 2.15-0ubuntu10.7 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.15-0ubuntu10 0
   500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

The output for apt-cache policy libc6

```
Installed: 2.19-18
Candidate: 2.19-18
Version table:
*** 2.19-18 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 0
    500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
 2.15-0ubuntu10.11 0
    500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
 2.15-0ubuntu10 0
    500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise/main amd64 Packages
    500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

output for apt-cache policy locales

```
locales:
Installed: 2.13+git20120306-3
Candidate: 2.13+git20120306-3
Version table:
*** 2.13+git20120306-3 0
    500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise/main amd64      Packages
    500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libc-dev-bin;apt-cache policy libc6`

Comment: What A.B. meant is that you should *run* those two commands in a terminal and then add their output on the terminal to this question

Comment: i cant believe i added the commands, thanks @kos

Comment: [Edit] your question again and give me the output of `apt-cache policy locales`

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer in progress

Downgrade the packages `libc6` and `libc6:i386`

```
sudo apt-get install libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.12
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386=2.15-0ubuntu10.12
```

You have installed version 2.19-18 and this version blocks the installation of `libc-dev-bin`

After that

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Start with my answer and give me a comment. I believe, we need a little bit more to repair you system.

Comment: i got this You might want to run `apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
` libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12)`    ` Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12) but 2.19-18 is to be   installed
 libc6:i386 : Recommends: libc6-i686:i386`   
 and at the end the suggested to run the last command you suggested

Comment: Do the downgrade also for libc6:i386 . I have changed my answer

Comment: it gives this  ` sudo apt-get install libc6=2.15-0ubuntu10.12`  
`Reading package lists... Done`    
`Building dependency tree`         
`Reading state information... Done`  
`You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:`  
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:`  
` libc6 : Depends: libc-bin (= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12)`  
`Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.15-0ubuntu10.12) but 2.19-18 is to be installed`  
` libc6:i386 : Recommends: libc6-i686:i386`  
 `Breaks: locales (< 2.19) but 2.13+git20120306-3 is to be installed`

Comment: Please start `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386=2.15-0ubuntu10.12`

Comment: And give me the output of `apt-cache policy libc6:i386`

Comment: still 2.19 is instlaled,the above command gave the same in the comment above,for somereasons i think 2.19 is getting reinstalled when dependencies are not met...here is the output of `apt-cache policy libc6:i386`  `  Installed: 2.19-18`
` Candidate: 2.19-18`
 ` Version table`:
` *** 2.19-18 0`
      `  100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`
   `  2.15-0ubuntu10.12 0
        500 mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt/ precise-updates/main i386 Packages`
        `500 http://rw.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28966/discussion-between-a-b-and-eliethesaiyan).